# Reading large numbers of text files in java

Tags: java, swing, filereader

I have an application that needs to read only specific content from a text file. I have to read the text from 10,000 different text files arranged in a folder and have to populate the content from all those text files into a single CSV file.

My application runs fine, but it is reading up to file number 999 only. No error, but is not reading file after 999.

Any ideas?

```
public void calculate(String location) throws IOException{
    String mylocation = location;
    File rep = new File(mylocation);
    File f2 = new File (mylocation + "\\" + "metricvalue.csv");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f2);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);

    if(rep.exists() && rep.isDirectory()){
        File name[] = rep.listFiles();

        for(int j = 0; j < name.length; j++){
            if(name[j].isFile()){
                String filename = name[j].getPath();
                String nameinfo = name[j].getName();
                File f1= new File (filename);

                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
                String line = null;

                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    if(line.contains(" |    @1    @2    % Correct")){
                        bw.write(nameinfo + ",");

                        while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if((line.indexOf("#" ) != -1)){
                                String info[] = line.split("\\s+");

                                String str = info[2] + "," + info[3] + ",";
                                bw.write(str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                bw.newLine();

                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: could u show us the code so that we get a lead

Comment: How can we possibly offer help without seeing your code?

Comment: Now that you have included a code example, try to follow the code that you have written to create a short, specific section that you think might have the problem. People will not read such a long code dump to solve one little problem. See sscce.org

Answer (score 1):

Your platform's file system is limited to 999 open files. You may need to increase the limit or  [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close--) the [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) explicitly:

```
fr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

How to debug:

Put a breakpoint at `File name[] = rep.listFiles();`

Open variables when Eclipse pauses and check that your array contains all of the file names you want. This will tell you if your problem is there or in your parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code. Here are a couple of pointers to get you started:

```
File name[] = rep.listFiles();
for(int j =0;j<name.length; j++) {
        if(name[j].isFile()) {
```

1. What is the size of the array? Figure it out. If there are 10000 elements in the array, that's how many iterations your loop will do, there is simply no other way. Just adding
   `System.out.println(name.length)` will answer this question for you
2. If the array is shorter than 10000, that's your answer, you simply counted your files incorrectly. If it is not, then your problem must be that one of the "files" isn't really a file (and the test of the `if` statement fails). Add an `else` statement to it, and print out the name ... Or better yet, remove this `if` at all (in general, avoid nested conditionals encompassing the entire body of an outer structure, especially, huge ones like this, it makes your code fragile, and logic very hard to follow), and replace it with

   ```
   if(!name[j].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Skipping " + name[j] + " because it is not a plain file.");
        continue;
    }
   ```

This will tell you which of 10000 files you are skipping.  If it does not print anything, that means, that you do in fact read all 10000 files, as you expect, and the actual problem causing the symptom you are investigating, is elsewhere.

Comment: Tried your suggestions. Array size show the correct number. Also none of the file were skipped. But still it is not reading

Comment: Do you see the contradiction here? If the number is correct, and nothing is skipped, that by definition means, that the correct number of files is read, doesn't it? You, probably mean something different when you say "not reading". How many times is `new FileReader(f1)` called?